# Connecting Samsung Galaxy Note 8 to a hardwired Ethernet

Tags: networking

Has anyone been able to connect the Galaxy Note 8 to a hardwired Ethernet network?  If so, what adapter was used?

There are times that I cannot use the Wi-Fi and need to connect using a wired network.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts StackExchange, what are you asking for exactly? A recommendation on the type of adapter or similar? Please read the [FAQ], recommendations are *off-topic*. :)

Comment: @t0mm13b Let's forget that this is a recommendation question. It looks like a valid question. I'm also interested to know if we can used wired connection with the tablet, and if there are devices / adapters that make it possible.

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, there are no USB-to-ethernet dongles that the Galaxy Note 8 recognizes. The long answer is Galaxy Note 8 only supports wireless network connections unfortunately; however that could change if Samsung decides to include support for wired ethernet dongles in updates to the Note 8.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Trendy-Micro-Mini-5pin-USB-To-RJ45-10-100M-Ethernet-Adapter-For-SamsungTable-PC-/400375887593) is what you are looking for...
[image: MicroUSB to Ethernet Adapter]

Comment: But does the Galaxy Note 8 include drivers to support its use?